# Export html table to excel format?

Tags: javascript, html, export-to-csv

I have a table that I created in the HTML page. I want to convert it to   XLS (excel) file format?

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Items</th>`enter code here`
      <th>Expenditure</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
    ......
  </tbody>
</table>
```